# How do you handle multi-argument JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, function, argument-passing, optional-parameters

I have defined my JavaScript function as follows:

```
function printCompanyName(company1, company2, company3, company4, company5)
{
document.write("<p>" + company1 + "</p>");
document.write("<p>" + company2 + "</p>");
document.write("<p>" + company3 + "</p>");
document.write("<p>" + company4 + "</p>");
document.write("<p>" + company5 + "</p>");
}
```

And called it as follows:

```
printCompanyName("Dell, Microsoft, Apple, Gizmodo, Amazon");
```

But I get the following output:

```
Dell, Microsoft, Apple, Gizmodo, Amazon

undefined

undefined

undefined

undefined
```

What gives!? I have been trying to figure this out for hrs. I want:

```
Dell
Microsoft
Apple
Gizmodo
Amazon
```

Comment: Let this be a lesson to you! Don't spend more than 1 hour before you (search, then ask) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call:

```
printCompanyName("Dell", "Microsoft", "Apple", "Gizmodo", "Amazon");
```

The way you're currently doing it you're passing in one company "Dell, Microsoft, Apple, Gizmodo, Amazon".

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my life because i was about to take it!

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a single string that happens to contain 4 commas.
Therefore, the first parameter contains that single string, and the other 4 are undefined.  (Sisnce you only gave one value)
Since Javascript parameters are optional, you don't get an error by not passing values for the other parameters.

You need to pass 5 different strings with commas between them, like this:

```
printCompanyName("Dell", "Microsoft", "Apple", "Gizmodo", "Amazon");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
printCompanyName("Dell", "Microsoft", "Apple", "Gizmodo", "Amazon");
```

Answer (score 0):

additional informations :

A way to use the function with the parameter as a string commas separated :

```
function printCompanyName(names)
{
    // also check the type of names (you know "if it is a string object")

    var data = names.split(',');    
    for(var i in data) {
        document.write("<p>" + data[i].trim() + "</p>");  
    }
}
```

exemple: `printCompanyName("Dell, Microsoft, Apple, Gizmodo, Amazon");`

Otherwise a multi parameters function using the internal arguments var :

```
function printCompanyName()
{
    for(var i in arguments) {
        document.write("<p>" + arguments[i] + "</p>");  
    }
}
```

exemple: `printCompanyName('Dell', 'Microsoft', 'Apple', 'Gizmodo', 'Amazon');` juste like SLaks said.